# multiple conditions in one if statement loaded from a file

Tags: node.js, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an if statement in my code that has multiple conditions, like this: `if(cond1 || cond2 || cond3 || cond4)`. These conditions may vary with time and I don't want to edit my code each time they change.

I'd like to store them in a file which would be easier to edit. something like this:

file `conditions.txt`:

```
cond1
cond2
cond3
cond4
```

and then in my code `if(loadedFile)`. My idea was to load the file into an array (`\n` separator) and then do `if(arr[1] || arr[2] || arr[3] || arr[4])` but that can't work since there is an unknown number of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Why is it easier to edit the conditions in a separate file, rather than the one that is executed?

To answer your question, if you really want to do this, look into [eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eval) for executing strings in node.

Seriously though, this is a very bad habit to get yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are evaluated in an array already, you can just make sure that none are false: `if (array.every(element => element)) {` To get them to be evaluated in the array, though, you'd need to use something like `eval`, which is quite unsecure. If you really want to keep them separate, I'd say you should refactor such that your conditions file is JS that simply exports the array itself for use in conditions later. Then you can import that array with `require()` in your main file.